# How do I add a standard deviation scaling factor to my cumulative normal distribution function in R?

Tags: r, statistics, psych

I am using the quickpsy package in R. I would like to have a parameter that scales the standard deviation that quickpsy calculates for the cumulative normal distribution function `cum_normal_fun`. Is there a way to do this? I can't pass in initial parameters because the quickpsy package is apparently calculating the parameters (mean and std dev) using probit analysis, so the parameters change with each dataset. This is my first time using R so I might be missing something obvious.

```
fit <- quickpsy(avg, Gain, nYes, n, grouping = (ID), prob = levels, xmin = 0, xmax = 2, fun = cum_normal_fun)
```

I looked at the source code for quickpsy and saw that cum_normal_function just calls `pnorm()`, so I tried defining my own function like:

```
scaled_dev_fun <- function(x,p) { pnorm(x, p[1],p[2]) }
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in fitpsy(d, x, k, n, random, within, between, grouping, xmin, xmax,  : 
  parini (initial parameters) must be specified.
```

From what I understand, I can't specify initial parameters for `parini` because that stops quickpsy from calculating them via probit analysis, which I want it to do. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I may misunderstand, but from looking at `?cum_normal_fun` you can define `mean` and `std dev` in the vector `p`. As in `cum_normal_fun(df, c(5, 0.3))`.

Comment: It helps to give us a data set or some sample code whenever possible.

Comment: I can't share the data unfortunately. And yes I can define the `mean` and `std dev` in `p`, but I've tried `fit <- quickpsy(avg, Gain, nYes, n, grouping = (ID), prob = levels, xmin = 0, xmax = 2, fun = cum_normal_fun(avg, c(0, 2)))` and I get the error: ` Error in get(funname) : object 'cum_normal_fun(avg, c(0, 2))' not found `

Comment: You might want to transfer some of the contents from your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729042/) over here, such as the code and error.

Comment: sorry about that, I posted that elsewhere and it got moved here. Updated this question.